# Border disappears during jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, border

I have created a sliding panel effect using jquery. Everything works but when the panels slide right the right-most panel loses its right border during the animation. I have not been able to figure out why. Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="panel" onclick="$(this).nextAll('.panel:not(.slid)').animate({left:'-=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).addClass('slid');
                        $(this).prevAll('.panel').andSelf().filter('.slid').animate({left:'+=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass('slid');"class="display" style="left:300px;"></div>
        <div class="panel" onclick="$(this).nextAll('.panel:not(.slid)').animate({left:'-=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).addClass('slid');
                        $(this).prevAll('.panel').andSelf().filter('.slid').animate({left:'+=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass('slid');" class="display" style="background-color: red; left:200px;"></div>
        <div class="panel" onclick="$(this).nextAll('.panel:not(.slid)').animate({left:'-=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).addClass('slid');
                        $(this).prevAll('.panel').andSelf().filter('.slid').animate({left:'+=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass('slid');"class="display" style="left:100px;"></div>
        <div class="panel" onclick="$(this).nextAll('.panel:not(.slid)').animate({left:'-=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).addClass('slid');
                        $(this).prevAll('.panel').andSelf().filter('.slid').animate({left:'+=400px'},{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass('slid');"class="display" style="left:0px;"></div>
    </div>
```

and css:

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left:175px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 800px;
    border: 4px groove #191970;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content .panel{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 4px groove #191970;
    background-color: white;
    margin: -4px;
}
```

Comment: What browser did you test it in. In works fine in FF Mac. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AEQks/2/

Comment: It seems to only be Chrome on pc

Comment: I am running Chrome on PC and all borders are intact using @ComputerArts fiddle.  I am running Chrome 18.0.1025.3  What version of Chrome are you running.

Comment: I just updated my Chrome to 23.0.1271.10 and I still have no missing borders in that fiddle.